# Create Poisson distribution

Tags: list-manipulation, distributions, discrete

I would like to make a phone call at the average arrival rate of λ = 300 [call / minute] per minute in the Poisson distribution of the telephone exchange and save it on the list.

I don't know even if I look at the site.
Give me advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simple calculation, you can do something like this to simulate a sequence of calls. The list returned gives the times of calls.

```
SeedRandom[1];
With[{callRate = 300, nCalls = 10}, 
  Accumulate @ RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[callRate], nCalls]]
```

> `{318, 634, 920, 1222, 1517, 1801, 2097, 2428, 2717, 3021}`

Note: I only use `SeedRandom[1]` to get reproducible results, so that others can check my work.

However, you are likely to want to make many such lists, so I recommend converting the calculation to a function. Like so:

```
calls[
    callRate_?NumberQ /; callRate > 0/callRate,
    nCalls_Integer /; nCalls > 0] := 
  Accumulate @ RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[callRate], nCalls]
```

Then

```
eedRandom[1]; calls[300, 10]
```

gives

> `{318, 634, 920, 1222, 1517, 1801, 2097, 2428, 2717, 3021}`

Comment: thank you very much for advice!